# Can't seem to figure out steps of factoring

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't seem to figure out how to get from

$5(5\cdot 3^{n}-3\cdot 2^{n})-6(5\cdot3^{n-1}-3\cdot2^{n-1})$

to

$(5\cdot5\cdot3-6\cdot5)3^{n-1}-(5\cdot3\cdot2-6\cdot3)2^{n-1}$

by factoring out $3^{n-1}$ and $2^{n-1}$

Comment: Use $a^{m+n}=a^m\cdot a^n, a^n=a\cdot a^{n-1}$

Comment: It should be $(5\cdot 5\cdot 3 - 6\cdot 5)3^{n-1} - (5\cdot 3\cdot 2 - 6\cdot 3)2^{n-1}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, yes, you are right. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @lab-bhattacharjee said, use the identity $a^{m+n}=a^m\cdot a^n, a^n=a\cdot a^{n-1}$.

$$5(5\cdot 3^{n}-3\cdot 2^{n})-6(5\cdot3^{n-1}-3\cdot2^{n-1}) = 5^2\cdot 3^n - 3\cdot 5\cdot 2^n-2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 3^{n-1}+2\cdot 3^2\cdot 2^{n-1} $$

$$=3^{n-1}(3\cdot 5^2-2 \cdot 3\cdot 5)-2^{n-1}(3\cdot 5\cdot 2-2\cdot 3^2).$$

Comment: I can't quite figure out what happens with the $2^{n}$ in $5^{2}\cdot3^{n}-3\cdot5\cdot2^{n}$. I can't factor a $3^{n-1}$ from that?

Comment: @GarthMarenghi after developing the parantheses, you obtain 4 terms, two contain $2^n$ and other two contain $3^n$.

Answer (score 2):

First distribute the indicated multiplications
$$5(5\cdot 3^n-3\cdot 2^n)-6(5\cdot 3^{n-1}-3\cdot 2^{n-1})\\
=5\cdot 5\cdot 3^n-3\cdot2^n\cdot 5-6\cdot 5\cdot 3^{n-1}+6\cdot 3\cdot 2^{n-1}\\
=5\cdot 5\cdot 3\cdot3^{n-1}-3\cdot2\cdot5\cdot2^{n-1}-6\cdot 5\cdot 3^{n-1}+6\cdot 3\cdot 2^{n-1}\\=(5\cdot 5 \cdot 3-6 \cdot 5)3^{n-1}-(5\cdot 3 \cdot 2-6\cdot3)2^{n-1}$$

Comment: The only thing I don't get is where does the $2^{n-1}$ got to in $5\cdot5\cdot3\cdot3^{n-1}-3\cdot2\cdot5\cdot2^{n-1}$? Because multiplying $(5\cdot5\cdot3-6\cdot5)$ with $3^{n-1}$ will give me $(5\cdot5\cdot5\cdot3\cdot3^{n-1}-6\cdot5\cdot3^{n-1})=5(5\cdot3-2\cdot3^{n})$

Comment: Sorry, I put a $5$ too much in $(5\cdot5\cdot5\cdot3\cdot3^{n-1})$